# Editing a "Fixed Width" Text File

Tags: microsoft-excel, text-editing, matlab

I had originally drafted this question in Engineering SE, but on second thought it makes a lot more sense here. I don't know if SuperUser SE just doesn't *have* MathJax formatting or if I don't know how to use it here, but my formatting got destroyed. Instead, I'll post a picture of my question and hopefully that'll suffice.

---

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated! (Also, if I was wrong a second time and this question doesn't go *here*, either, let me know and I'll move it to a new location.)

Comment: You can read the text file with fopen or textread, and you can address substrings pretty easily. If YourString = "This is text" , then YourString(6:12) returns "s text"

Comment: The problem is that I need to read in strings with fixed widths, edit some cells *as if they were numbers*, and then output to a text file as strings with fixed widths. So it's not as simple as just string manipulation, and while I can always use str2num on some cells, using num2str doesn't preserve my fixed width condition.

Comment: Why not use num2str with a formatspec that suits our needs, and then grab the fixed-length substring?

Comment: Maybe I didn't read the documentation enough, but what I'm specifically looking for is converting a number like "3.1415" to "  3.1415", where there are two leading blank characters so the whole string is eight characters long. I don't know what format spec this corresponds to - %8s didn't work, for example, because it gave me things like "2.000000e3," which is ten characters. I also have no way of knowing a priori whether my numbers are going to be floats or integers, so that complicates the issue a bit.

Comment: Welocme to Superuser. Do not post your questions as images. It makes them impossible to be searched and people with visual challenges cannot read them. If you still have the quesiton in editable format, request you to remove the image part and replace that with text part

Comment: I can just rewrite the question and remove the, that's not a problem - my only question is does SuperUser SE use MathJax formatting? If not, I'll have some problems trying to transcribe the few lines that are supposed to be in perfect character alignment.

Comment: For your character alignment, you could use `backticks` or four-space indents to format as monospace.

Answer (score 0):

There is more to working with fixed with data transfer than is in scope for this question. to answer the question,
Assume the cell we need to convert to this format is in cell G8
there are 3 possibilities,

- The length of G8 is less than 8
  =rept("0",8-len(g8))&g8
  this adds padding of zeros in front
- The length of g8 is 8
  =G8
  no work is needed
- The length of g8 is greater than 8
  =left(g8,8)
  This truncates g8

to make it all work in a single equation without using naming -

=IF(LEN(G8)<8,REPT("0",8-LEN(G8))&G8,IF(LEN(G8)>8,LEFT(G8,8),G8))

Comment: This assumes that truncating is allowed for numbers with a lot of digits and the decimal point will be within the first 8 positions.